# How to Parse MIME without multiple parts in it

Tags: java, mime, mime4j

I need `<xml>__content__</xml>` part from the following response string in java

```
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8; name=response_xml<xml>...</xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

---

Now that I understand what you need, you can use a simple `regex` to extract the text between the tags `<xml>` and `</xml>`

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a="Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8; name=response_xml<xml>content</xml>";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<xml>(.+?)</xml>");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(a);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is a multipart message received from server. I need `<xml></xml>` part to be parsed.

Comment: This looks good for me. But is there a standard MIME way to work it out please. Thanks.